# How to get Debugging Symbols for Valgrind using a QMake File

Tags: c++, qt, unix, valgrind, qmake

Is this possible? The reason why I'm asking is because I'd like to see the line number for the file being used, rather than a hex-dump of various addresses of which I have little idea of what I'm reading.

Comment: If using GCC (which include the g++ compiler) try adding the flag `-g`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this to you configuration file :

```
CONFIG += qt debug
```

See [this](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-tutorial.html#making-an-application-debuggable) for mode details.